# Transferring basemap - cartopy

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I am using basemap on Python 2.7 but would like to go for Python 3, and therefor, moving to cartopy. It would be fantastic if you would give me some advises how to change my code from basemap to cartopy:

This is the basemap code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    # plot map without continents and coastlines
    m = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)
    # draw map boundary, transparent
    m.drawmapboundary()
    m.drawcoastlines()
    # draw paralells and medians, no labels
    if (TheLatInfo[1] == len(TheLatList)) & (TheLonInfo[1] == len(TheLonList)):
        m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90.,30.))
        m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180.,60.))

grids = m.pcolor(LngArrLons,LngArrLats,MSKTheCandData,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,latlon='TRUE')
```

This is the cartopy example I found and have changed some bits:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cpf

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_boundary
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False)
plt.show()
```

I am not sure about how to set the gridlines in the exact positions and how to color them black instead of grey. Furthermore, I wonder how to insert/overlay my actual map with data then. Is "ax.pcolor" well enough supported by cartopy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**To color your gridlines black**, you can use a `color=` keyword:

```
ax.gridlines(color='black')
```

**To specify lat/lon gridline placement**, you really only need a few extra lines, if you don't care about labels:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

gl = ax.gridlines(color='black')
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-180, -90, 0, 90, 180])
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-90,-45,0,45,90])
```

(As of writing this, Robinson projections don't support gridline *labels*.)

**To overlay your data on the map**,`pcolor` should work, but it's famously slow.  I would recommend `pcolormesh`, though you can substitute one for another in this syntax:

```
ax.pcolormesh(lon_values, lat_values, data)
```

Note that if your data come on a **different** projection than the map projection you're plotting (typically true), you *need to specify the data's projection* in the plotting syntax using the `transform=` keyword.  That tells cartopy to transform your data from their original projection to that of the map.  Plate Carrée is the same as cylindrical equidistant (typical for climate model output, for example):

```
ax.pcolormesh(lon_values, lat_values, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```